# pandas: filter rows with list elements beginning with string?

Tags: pandas

> Blockquote

I have the following dataframe.

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'a': [['foo', 'bar'], ['bar'], ['fah', 'baz']})
```

I'd like to return just the rows with values of a beginning `f` in them - i.e. the first and third rows.

This is what I've tried:

```
 d[d.a.is_in('f')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `any` in list comprehension with generator:

```
d = d[[any(y.startswith('f') for y in x) for x in d['a']]]
print (d)
            a
0  [foo, bar]
2  [fah, baz]
```

**Detail**: (convert to list only for sample)

```
print ([list(y.startswith('f') for y in x) for x in d['a']])
[[True, False], [False], [True, False]]
```

Comment: Sorry! I said in the question but not my example code that I actually want to find all rows with strings beginning with `f` - is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `.apply()`, iterating over the individual list elements, checking with `.startswith()` and evaluating the length of the resultant list:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [['foo', 'bar'], ['bar'], ['fah', 'baz']]})
df = df[df.a.apply(lambda x: len([el for el in x if el.startswith('f')]) > 0)]
print(df)
```

which results in:

```
            a
0  [foo, bar]
2  [fah, baz]
```